# why will the bandit proc a valkyrie swing without getting hit only around half the time?

Tags: clash-royale

The bandit, when dashing into a valkyrie,seems to have a 50% chance to block it and be invincible, and the other times, it gets hit. Why exactly does this happen?

Comment: If anyone else has a better explanation for that inconsistency, please let me know, this is the only one i have discovered, but there probably is a better and more in depth explanation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valkyrie will only be blocked if it hasn't attacked before, if you just spawn it at the bridge and you use a bandit that dashes into it, it will be blocked. But hypothetically, you played a goblin gang and they used the valkyrie in the middle of it, killing it while it has attacked only once, then a bandit dashes into it, it will hit the bandit.the reason for this must be a stored data bug or an intended mechanic. Otherwise, it is a definite inconsistency in that match up.